# Efficient way to call .Sum() on multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have a function that uses LINQ to get data from the database and then I call that function in another function to sum all the individual properties using `.Sum()` on each individual property. I was wondering if there is an efficient way to sum all the properties at once rather than calling `.Sum()` on each individual property. I think the way I am doing as of right now, is very slow (although untested).

```
public OminitureStats GetAvgOmnitureData(int? fnsId, int dateRange)
{
    IQueryable<OminitureStats> query = GetOmnitureDataAsQueryable(fnsId, dateRange);
    
    int pageViews = query.Sum(q => q.PageViews);
    int monthlyUniqueVisitors = query.Sum(q => q.MonthlyUniqueVisitors);
    int visits = query.Sum(q => q.Visits);
    double pagesPerVisit = (double)query.Sum(q => q.PagesPerVisit);
    double bounceRate = (double)query.Sum(q => q.BounceRate);

    return new OminitureStats(pageViews, monthlyUniqueVisitors, visits, bounceRate, pagesPerVisit);
}
```

```
private IQueryable<OminitureStats> GetOmnitureDataAsQueryable(int? fnsId, int dateRange)
{
    var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    var nDays = yesterday.AddDays(-dateRange);

    if (fnsId.HasValue)
    {
        IQueryable<OminitureStats> query = from o in lhDB.omniture_stats
                                            where o.fns_id == fnsId
                                                    && o.date <= yesterday
                                                    && o.date > nDays
                                            select new OminitureStats ( 
                                                o.page_views.GetValueOrDefault(), 
                                                o.monthly_unique.GetValueOrDefault(),
                                                o.visits.GetValueOrDefault(),
                                                (double)o.bounce_rate.GetValueOrDefault()
                                            );
        return query;
    }
    return null;
}
```

```
public class OminitureStats
{
    public OminitureStats(int PageViews, int MonthlyUniqueVisitors, int Visits, double BounceRate)
    {
        this.PageViews = PageViews;
        this.MonthlyUniqueVisitors = MonthlyUniqueVisitors;
        this.Visits = Visits;
        this.BounceRate = BounceRate;
        this.PagesPerVisit = Math.Round((double)(PageViews / Visits), 1);
    }

    public OminitureStats(int PageViews, int MonthlyUniqueVisitors, int Visits, double BounceRate, double PagesPerVisit)
    {
        this.PageViews = PageViews;
        this.MonthlyUniqueVisitors = MonthlyUniqueVisitors;
        this.Visits = Visits;
        this.BounceRate = BounceRate;
        this.PagesPerVisit = PagesPerVisit;
    }

    public int PageViews { get; set; }
    public int MonthlyUniqueVisitors { get; set; }
    public int Visits { get; set; }
    public double PagesPerVisit { get; set; }
    public double BounceRate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

IIRC you can do all the sums in one go (as long as the query is translated to SQL) with

```
var sums = query.GroupBy(q => 1)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    PageViews = g.Sum(q => q.PageViews),
                    Visits = g.Sum(q => q.Visits),
                    // etc etc
                })
                .Single();
```

This will give you one object which contains all the sums as separate properties.

Comment: Thanks Jon. But I am getting `NotSupportedException` at `var sums ...` . but it has nothing to do with your solution. Because I tested the way I was doing it and it would still throw this exception. Does it has anything to do with `IQueryable<OmnitureStats>` part?

Comment: And also how is your solution different than the way I am doing. I still have to call .Sum() on each individual properties. Thanks

Comment: @SherCoder: Regarding the exception, you will have to tell us exactly what kind of `IQueryable` you are working with. Regarding how this is better: all the sums are expressed as part of the same expression tree, so the SQL translation layer can pull them out in just one query.

Comment: I updated my question. You can see the code that I use to get data from the table.

Comment: For my own benefit, is the semantically different than the simple loop that I proposed (well, I'm almost certain it is)?  Does it result in more efficient code because the query being executed on the back end is more specific?

Comment: @EdS.: The loop requires that the full dataset be transferred from (I am assuming) the SQL server to the client so that the points can be summed. That might be quite a bit of data, plus the overhead of serializing/deserializing etc.

Comment: @Jon: Yeah, that's what I figured.  Thanks.  Deleting my response as this would seem to be a better solution.

Comment: @Jon: Do you have any idea why I get `NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initilizers are supported in LINQ to Entities`. I added the class that I am using in my code.

Comment: @SherCoder: Not really because you haven't said what kind of ORM you are using.

Comment: @Jon: Sorry. I am using Linq to Entities.

Comment: Not using any ORM, but speaking in terms of in-memory performance. I think those 2 `Sum` calls will result in 2 loops, so it's not that good.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it was throwing the `NotSupportedException`. I learned that `Linq to Entity` does not support constructors with parameters, So deleted the constructors and made changes in my query. I am a novice C# programmer, so let me know if my solution could be improved, but as of right now it is working fine.

```
public class OminitureStats
{
    public int PageViews { get; set; }
    public int MonthlyUniqueVisitors { get; set; }
    public int Visits { get; set; }
    public double PagesPerVisit { get; set; }
    public double BounceRate { get; set; }
}


private IQueryable<OminitureStats> GetOmnitureDataAsQueryable(int? fnsId, int dateRange)
{
    var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    var nDays = yesterday.AddDays(-dateRange);

    if (fnsId.HasValue)
    {
        IQueryable<OminitureStats> query = from o in lhDB.omniture_stats
                                           where o.fns_id == fnsId
                                                 && o.date <= yesterday
                                                 && o.date > nDays
                                           select new OminitureStats() { 
                                               o.page_views.GetValueOrDefault(), 
                                               o.monthly_unique.GetValueOrDefault(),
                                               o.visits.GetValueOrDefault(),
                                               (double)o.bounce_rate.GetValueOrDefault()
                                           };
        return query;
    }
    return null;
}
```